# preg_match get multiple

Tags: php, regex

I have a page like w/e more HTML 
I need to grab all the data between the tags  and not the first one. Currently I use

```
<?php([^<]*?)\?>/"
```

But it grabs the first one and stops. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Look into the function [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all).

Answer (score 1):

use this with `preg_match_all()`

```
preg_match_all("/<?php([^<]*?)\?>/siU",$html,$output);
print_r($output[1]);
```

Comment: The `s` and `U` modifiers are not needed.